# HTML Entities in Post Title

Tags: mysql, wp-insert-post

I'm inserting posts into wordpress using a script which is loaded through CRON. Before inserting each post I am checking whether the post with the same title exists or not. Below is the snippet I'm using:

```
if( is_null(get_page_by_title( $page_title, 'OBJECT', $post_type )) ) {
    // Create post object
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title' => "Food & Wine",  // this is example and it actually inserts $page_title.
        'post_content' => 'Dummy content',
        'post_status' => 'draft',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type' => $post_type,
    );
    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $my_post );
} else {
    echo 'Post already exists.';
}
```

Now this insertion part works pretty well, but it stores '&' as html entity (`&amp;`) in the database. So in the database, the post title looks like "Food & Wine". In the list of posts admin screen, the title looks fine with '&' and once I go to the edit screen, it shows `&amp;`.

This causes the first 'if' condition to return TRUE and it inserts a duplicate post. My database collation type is "utf8_general_ci". Well this works on my local MAMP installation, but fails on my shared host.

I would like to know what is wrong in the code and how should this situation be handled. Also is it suggested to escape html entities for the 'post_content'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the crux of the question is this:

> This causes the first 'if' condition to return TRUE and it inserts a
>   duplicate post.

Check for the `post_name` instead. That value is normalized to lowercase and dashes by [`sanitize_title_with_dashes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_with_dashes) so you won't have this issue. That value is also the one that WordPress enforces as unique, and the one used as a permalink.

Comment: So that means I have to fire a query using $wpdb object right? Or is there any inbuilt wordpress function to take care of this? Well this would be an immediate solution to my problem, but I would like to know why on my local MAMP installation wordpress stores & as & and on my server it stores as `&amp;`?

Locally I am running MySql 5.5.25 and PHP 5.2.17 and on my hosting server I have MySql 5.5.23 and PHP 5.2.17.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this possibility. Although it's quit obvious (in hindsight), I've been struggling with a similar problem for a few day's now :). Many thanks (y)